# A wrong id is assigned to each new object being created in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I deleted some objects belonging to one of my models in Django. Now when I create a new object, a wrong id is assigned to this object. This id is not successive. How can I address this problem?
The example:

```
 >>> Programmer.objects.all().values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Linus Torvalds','occupation': 'Software enginner'}, 
{'id': 2, 'name': 'Tim Cook', 'occupation': 'CEO'}, 
{'id': 3, 'name': 'Elon Musk', 'occupation': 'Entrepreneur, engineer'}]>

 >>> p4=Programmer(name='Mark Zuckerberg')
 >>> p4.save()
 >>> Programmer.objects.all().values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Linus Torvalds', 'occupation': 'Software enginner'}, 
{'id': 2, 'name': 'Tim Cook', 'occupation': 'CEO'}, 
{'id': 3, 'name': 'Elon Musk', 'occupation': 'Entrepreneur, engineer'}, 
{'id': 15, 'name': 'Mark Zuckerberg', 'occupation': None}]>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are saving a new object I believe the Django just pulls the next unused id off of the database. Thus, if ids 4 through 14 were used, they don't get reused - even if you have since deleted those records.

Comment: @aspiring That might work but do you really want to track them manually? If these correspond to a piece of data you're picking up from somewhere else,  you might want to set them manually and shouldn't rely on Django to set them for you. In most cases, however, the ID is meaningless - it's just a way to find a particular record and, as such, what the number is shouldn't matter.